# Is the pdfDocument included in the DocuSign enveloped COMPLETED event the latest version?

Tags: docusignapi

In my integration app with DocuSign, it has a webhook to receive the event from DocuSign. It received an enveloped COMPLETED event notification and downloaded the pdfDocument in the event. But the pdfDocument, both the signed copy and the certificate of completion, are not the latest version as one of the signatures is not in included in the document.

Is the pdfDocument included in the DocuSign enveloped COMPLETED event always the latest version? 
Is there a scenario, that the event is COMPLETED, but the pdfDocument in the event notification is not?

Answer (score 0):

If the notification message has envelope status of `completed` then the included document should be the final version.

Make sure that you are either checking the envelope status or are only requesting an envelope==completed status.

Note that the XML includes many `status` nodes, so you need to be careful to check the envelope's status node, not a recipient's.

Comment: I did check the envelope status code to ensure it is completed. The code works fine for long time and handles the status correctly. It just happened one time. In this case, the app didn't receive one of the recipient's "completed" status event but did receive the envelope "completed" status event. And the documents in the envelope "completed" event seem not to be the latest version.

Comment: Because of the way the default (aggregate) queuing system works, it is possible but very unlikely. Switch to SIM queuing to ensure it will not happen again. See the Updates section of the Admin tool